# Grails: Dynamically change domain's constraints in controller

Tags: grails

I'm a Grails beginner. I have a Domain class which has domainName field in Grails (ver. 2.0.1). In my DomainConstraints.groovy, I have:

```
constraints = {
    domainName blank: false, matches: "^([^.]{0,63}\\.)*([^.]{1,63})\$"
}
```

but depending on some situation, i want to make this domainName field "blank: true" or "blank: false". I'm not validating my domain class against the actual database, so sync with the domain class and the actual table is not an issue.

So, I want to do something like this (code below is from my imagination):

```
if(something){
   Domain.constraints.removeAttr('blank')
} else {
   Domain.constraints.addAttr('blank', 'true')
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725059/grails-custom-validator-for-domain-class

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
class DomainConstraints {
  Boolean validateBlankFlag
  String domainName
  static transients = [validateBlankFlag]

  static constraints = {
    domainName validator :  { val,obj -> !val?.equals("") || !obj.validateBlankFlag}

  }
}
```

Then just set the `validateBlankFlag` on the domain object depending on whether you want to allow blank values or not.  You may not even need the `validateBlankFlag` property if you can make the decision based on other property values within the DomainConstraints object.

Comment: @cweston the code above shows `validateBlankFlag` in the transients array.